# ngClass hidden hides content but doesn't show it on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, mobile-safari

ngClass validation toggles the class properly and shows in the DOM, however it is not rendered on the screen.

this only happens on Safari on iOS.

```
<div class="filter-section">
  <div class="filter-section-header">
    {{ 'TYPE_OF_DOCUMENTS' | translate }}
  </div>

  <app-radio-buttons class="type-options" [control]="filtersForm?.get('type')" [options]="enabledDocumentTypes"
    name="type">
  </app-radio-buttons>
</div>


<div [ngClass]="{'hidden': type === DocumentType.REGULATORY_DOCUMENTS}" class="filter-section">
  <div class="filter-section-header">
    {{ 'PERIOD' | translate }}
  </div>

  <app-radio-buttons class="period-options" [control]="filtersForm?.get('period')" [options]="periodList"
    name="period">
  </app-radio-buttons>
</div>

<div [ngClass]="{'hidden': period !== DocumentPeriod.SPECIFIC_DATES || type === DocumentType.REGULATORY_DOCUMENTS}">
  <app-mobile-date-input class="date-input date-from" [class.date-input-focused]="!fromDate"
    [control]="filtersForm.get('fromDate')" [label]="(brand === 'cg' ? 'FROM_DATE' : 'FROM') | translate"
    [maxDate]="today" name="fromDate"></app-mobile-date-input>

  <app-mobile-date-input class="date-input date-to" [class.date-input-focused]="fromDate && !toDate"
    [control]="filtersForm.get('toDate')" [label]="(brand === 'cg' ? 'TO_DATE' : 'TO') | translate"
    [minDate]="fromDate" name="toDate"></app-mobile-date-input>
</div>
```